# Jupyter Lab Not Opening

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am a beginner. Please help. **When I pass the `jupyter lab` command the following error occurs:-**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\parijat basak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\server.py", line 20, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import aliases, flags, NotebookApp as ServerApp
  File "c:\users\parijat basak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 51, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\Users\Parijat Basak\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\Parijat Basak\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Parijat Basak\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Parijat Basak\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\Parijat Basak\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\Parijat Basak\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Parijat Basak\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\parijat basak\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\parijat basak\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Parijat Basak\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-lab.EXE\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\parijat basak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labapp.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jupyterlab_server import slugify, WORKSPACE_EXTENSION
  File "c:\users\parijat basak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .app import LabServerApp
  File "c:\users\parijat basak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\app.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .server import ServerApp
  File "c:\users\parijat basak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab_server\server.py", line 26, in <module>
    from jupyter_server.base.handlers import (                          # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyter_server'
```

Please help!!! I am unable to use Jupyter Lab anymore and it is extremly problematic for me!

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, it may be faster, and easier is to reinstall Jupyter Lab (maybe create a new conda environment if needed).
One more thing, you might consider backing up your conda environment when everything is smooth:
https://www.anaconda.com/blog/moving-conda-environments